# The Taylor series of the squared logarithm

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, harmonic-numbers

> Prove that the Taylor series about the origin of the function $[\log(1-z)]^2$ is given by 
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2H_{n}}{n+1} z^{n+1}$$
>   where 
>   $$H_{n} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{j}$$
>   is the $n$-th partial sum of the harmonic series.
>   (Hint: Write $\log(1-z)$ as a power series for $|z| < 1$ and use Cauchy products for $[\log(1-z)]^2$)

I've been working on this question since last night and I've been trying to follow the hint and look at the derivative of $\log(1-z)$ and then integrate that, but all attempts have been futile.

Really lost here...

Comment: What did you get for the Taylor series of $\log (1-z)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer 
Σ (z^(k+1))/(k+1)

Comment: You lost a minus sign there, but since we're squaring it, that's not a deal-breaker. Okay, now the Cauchy product. What was the general formula for the coefficients of the Cauchy product of two power series?

Comment: @DanielFischer so if i'm not wrong i got
Sum from k=0 to k=n of (a_k)*(b_(n-k))

Comment: Right. Now note that here $a_k = b_k$, since we're squaring, and that $a_0 = 0$, so you get $$c_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k\cdot a_{n-k}.$$ Then fill in what $a_k$ is. You get a sum, and you want to show that that equals $$c_n = \frac{2H_{n-1}}{n}.$$ The natural first step is to multiply both sides of the should-be-equation by $n$, then play around a bit to try and see the equality. If you find the right turn, it's quite easy. (If you don't, it's not easy.)

Comment: yeah haha it's all about that right turn that's got me

Comment: Here's a hint: $n = (n-k) + k$.

Comment: okay let me try that!

Comment: Since $a_0 = 0$, the terms $a_0\cdot a_n$ and $a_n\cdot a_0$ can be omitted. For uniformity of expression, they should be omitted, makes things easier. For the $H_n$ vs. $H_{n-1}$ thing, note that $c_n$ is the coefficient of $z^n$, your given series is written with exponents $n+1$.

Comment: so i brought the n inside the summation, used the hint, got to 
(n-k+k)/(k+1)(n-k+1) .. lost again =/

Comment: You're using the wrong $a_k$. Note: $a_k$ is the coefficient of $z^k$, not that of $z^{k+1}$.

Comment: mhm are you implying that a_k = 1/k